# Si me mandan una URL en el GET redirigir a esa URL

Tags: php

Como bien dice el título del post si me llegan a mandar una `url` quiero redirigirme a esa `url`.¿Cómo lo haría de forma completa?

```
if (isset($_GET["URL"])) {
    header("Location: public_area.php?url=$actual_link");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Luego de comprobar si existe la otra url, almacénala en una variable que luego usarás para armar la cabecera de redirección. Además, utiliza el método [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.exit.php) luego de colocar la cabecera, de esta manera se detiene el script actual y se manda el redirect a la nueva url.

```
if (isset($_GET["url"])) {
    $url = $_GET["url"];
    header("Location: $url");
    exit();
}
```

En caso que no quieras utilizar una variable adicional, puedes concatenar el valor del parámetro directamente a la cadena de la cabecera:

```
if (isset($_GET["url"])) {
    header("Location: ".$_GET["url"]);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: tendría que declarar la variables url?

Comment: @Serj no recuerdo si puedes utilizar `$_GET["url"]` directamente en el string y será evaluado. No tengo un ambiente a la mano para hacer la prueba.

Comment: @Serj hice una [prueba simple en ideone](http://ideone.com/WVoiob) y al parecer tienes que declararlo en una nueva variable. No es posible utilizar `"$arreglo['llave']"` en PHP 5.6.4.

Comment: como lo dejaría ?

Comment: Pues acá tienes 2 formas de cómo lo dejarías. También tienes [la respuesta de @Elenasys](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4015/227). Elige el que creas más conveniente para ti.

Comment: El valor de `$url` debería ser procesado con [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) para evitar posibles errores. También, dependiendo de la versión de PHP que se use, podría haber problemas de seguridad (por [inyección de encabezados HTTP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_de_encabezado_HTTP)) si no se sanea la entrada.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro completamente cierto. Si la url no está saneada, puede llevar a problemas de seguridad.

Answer (score 2):

Toma el valor de la url después de comprobar que existe y mediante **[header()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)** agregas la url que deseas redireccionar, al finalizar utiliza el método [**exit()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) para finalizar el script :

```
if(isset($_GET['URL'])) {
   $url = $_GET['URL'];
   header('Location: ' .$url);
   exit();
}
```

también puedes usar el método [**die()**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_die.asp) para finalizar el script

```
if(isset($_GET['URL'])) {
   $url = $_GET['URL'];
   header('Location: ' .$url);
   die();
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias a ti también

Comment: un placer Serj =).